# get attribute option value in magento 2.1 using helper in custom module in data.php

Tags: magento2

Ex : color attribute code, While adding product from admin panel, if we select color attribute option using dropdown (Green, Blue, yellow ....), selected color i want to set to particular product title color in list.phtml file,

how to write code to access color attribute option in custom module in data.php helper file, and how to retrieve in list.phtml file.

Please suggest me solution,thank you